# Showing a Process is a Martingale with Sum of I.I.D.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am proving the follow:

Let $V_1,V_2....$ be independent $N(0,1)$ random variables.  Let $S_n=V_1+...V_n$ and $X_n=e^{S_n - n/2}$.  Let $F_{n}^{V}$ be the sigma algebra generated by $V_1,...,V_n.$  Prove that $X_n,F_{n}^{V}$ is a martingale.

The process trivially satisfies that $X_n$  is $F_n$ measurable for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $X_n \in L_1.$  It just remains to show that $X_s=E(X_n|F_s)$ for all $s \le n$.

I think I have an idea but I'm stuck on some of the details.  We have $E(X_n|F_s)=E(e^{S_n - n/2}|F_s).$  I think we can split this expression, but I'm not sure if I'm splitting it correctly.  $E(e^{S_n - n/2}|F_s)=e^{S_{n-1}-n/2}E(e^{V_n}|F_s).$

Given that the r.v. are independent we have,  $e^{S_{n-1}-n/2}E(e^{V_n}|F_s)=e^{S_{n-1}-n/2}E(e^{V_n}).$  Since $V_n$ is N(0,1) we can show that $E(e^{V_n})=e^{1/2}.$  Then together we have $e^{S_{n-1}-n/2}E(e^{V_n})=e^{S_{n-1}-n/2}e^{1/2})=e^{S_{n-1}-(n-1)/2}=X_{n-1}$.

Is this a correct line of reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

Your calculations are right for the case $s=n-1$. Only this case you can take out $e^{S_{n-1}-n/2}$ from the conditional expectation. For general $s<n$ you can repeat just the same: 
$$
E\left(X_n\mid F_s\right)=E\left(e^{S_n - n/2}\mid F_s\right)=E\left(\frac{e^{S_n - n/2}}{e^{S_s-s/2}}\times \underbrace{e^{S_s-s/2}}_{X_s}\biggm| F_s\right)=X_s\cdot E\left(e^{S_n-S_s-(n-s)/2}\mid F_s\right).
$$
Next, $S_n-S_s=V_{s+1}+\ldots+V_n$ does not depend on $F_s$ and the summands are independent from each other. Split the expectation into the product:
$$E\left(X_n\mid F_s\right)=X_s\cdot \underbrace{\prod_{i=s+1}^n E\left[e^{V_i}\right]}_{e^{(n-s)/2}}\cdot e^{-(n-s)/2}=X_s.$$